# Handling right click menu items in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I want to right click and go the 5th option that is "copy link address".

I have tried the following code and this is the only thing i could i could find on then internet

```
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
   WebElement elementLocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[(@id = \"u_0_1n\")]"));
     TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2); 
   actions.contextClick(elementLocator).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
```

This code actually scrolls the page downward instead of moving down the right click menu as if the right click menu was never there.

Comment: Try Robot class for keyboard events related to windows native UI . Actions dont have support to interact with native windows UI elements .

Comment: can u guide me how to implement robot class here.

Comment: you dont have to implement it entirely its there in java just do some more research

Comment: Yeah thanks... i have done it successfully

Comment: Using `Robot` class to get the "link address"(url) is a terrible idea. Check if there is an `href` attribute for the `WebElement` and use `getAttribute` method to extract the url.

Answer (score 0):

Using context clicks is not something I would recommend as it violates [Parallel Testing Best Practices](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+-+Best+Practices)

The tests need to be [small, atomic, and autonomous](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Best+Practices%3A+Use+Small%2C+Atomic%2C+Autonomous+Tests) and your current approach assumes that the browser has to be in focus. It means that you will neither be able to do anything while the test is running nor run the tests in parallel.

So instead I would suggest:

1. Extract [href](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) attribute from the link you want to click
2. Use [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) and [Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) function in order to open the link in the new tab
3. [Switch](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo--) to the new tab

Example code:

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[(@id = \"u_0_1n\")]"));
String url = link.getAttribute("href");
driver.executeScript("window.open('" + url + "');");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().stream().reduce((f, s) -> s).orElse(null));
```

Comment: Thank you... this saved me a lot of lines of code and robots and action class. :p